# ... results in lower evaluation measures

Tags: idiomatic-language

A sentence like

> ... results in lower evaluation measures

seems OK to me, but Google didn't find even a single result for "in lower evaluation measures". Is there any problem with the construction? What else can be used? 
Assume that we are evaluating something by one method of evaluation that the reader knows we are using, so I prefer to say evaluation measures instead of just measures to convey that the measures obtained by that evaluation method are lowered, other evaluation methods may have different results.

Comment: Warp the sentence in blockqutoe please.

Comment: What are the "measures"? I think a different word for this may get more hits. Such as "evaluation scores" or "evaluation results".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have noted that "lower evaluation measures" does get lots of hits. Eg

> Biological design had lower evaluation measures reflecting physical requirements.

So the only question is "can I use 'results in (something)". And there are examples of this too:

> Using Pillai scores derived
>   from MANOVAs results in measures of fronting ...

There is nothing wrong with the construction "... results in lower evaluation measures"  But as with any sufficiently long phrase, it isn't in google's index.

Comment: Even, "lower evaluation measures" doesn't bring many results for me: 10 results. Do you get more results?

Comment: That's about as expected.   There is evidence of use.   These are three less common words (measure is quite common as a verb, but less so as noun)